# Password may contain illegal characters

Tags: 7, users, forms

Is it possible to change an option or overwrite the password validation so that a user can add characters like `é` to their password?

Comment: You already can use chars like 'é' in your password. In your installation you can't? Which form?

Comment: Strange, when I try to use password nééles I get an error: The password contains an illegal character.

Comment: Have you installed any passwod or user related modules?

Comment: I've installed the LoginToboggan module, maybe that could be the problem?

Comment: Yes, LoginToboggan, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Login Toboggan config page:

> LoginToboggan automatically performs basic password validation for
>   illegal characters. If you would additionally like to have a minimum
>   password length requirement, select the length here, or set to 'None'
>   for no password length validation.

If you check the logintoboggan_validate_pass you see:

```
  if (preg_match('/[\x{80}-\x{A0}'.          // Non-printable ISO-8859-1 + NBSP
                   '\x{A1}-\x{F7}'.          // Latin punctuations
                   '\x{AD}'.                 // Soft-hyphen
                   '\x{2000}-\x{200F}'.      // Various space characters
                   '\x{2028}-\x{202F}'.      // Bidirectional text overrides
                   '\x{205F}-\x{206F}'.      // Various text hinting characters
                   '\x{FEFF}'.               // Byte order mark
                   '\x{FF01}-\x{FF60}'.      // Full-width latin
                   '\x{FFF9}-\x{FFFD}]/u',   // Replacement characters
                   $pass)) {
    return t('The password contains an illegal character.');
  }
```

So your problem comes from Login Toboggan.

I think this automatic validation is only performed when user can set the password int he register process.

Comment: It is necessary that the password can be set in the register process, is there a way to make sure that the user can add é?

Comment: You can config as you need. Check the Login Toboggan module config page and unset the 'Set password' checkbox.

Comment: If you consider that module behaviors is wrong don't forget to comment in this issue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2147893 (I'm doing it, because I think this is a bug)

Comment: Hmm okay, thanks for the answers! To bad there isn't a way to overwrite this.